# Remote Linux access issue: Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, remmina

I am trying to access a Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS remote server installed on cloud and I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my local machine. I have set a OpenVPN connection to connect to the remote server.

While I am able to connect to remote Ubuntu via Remmina, I am not able to connect using terminal.

When I `ssh x1.x2.x3.x4` from terminal, I am prompted for password `user@x1.x2.x3.x4's password:`, entering password returns `user@x1.x2.x3.x4: Permission denied (publickey,password).`

Let me know if I should provide more information.

Comment: Seems likely to be a server side issue. But 16.04 is EOL and not supported at askubuntu. You should upgrade your machine, even more urgent as its used as a server and exposed to the internet.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Answer (score 0):

I realised `user@x1.x2.x3.x4` was no legitimate user on `x1.x2.x3.x4`, and `ssh user_xx@x1.x2.x3.x4` did the job